# How is vector w on the same plane formed by vectors u and v

Tags: vectors, independence, plane-geometry

Given u =[1,-1,0], v=[0,1,-1] and w=[-1,0,1], I realize that these are not independent vectors since $-1\cdot u - v = w$ , but I struggle to "see" how they are on the same plane --and i've found an app to allow me to easily plot them in 3D I can see it, but I still can't.
[image]

I know this is basic, but I'm still struggling to see this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Vector $w$ is in a plane generated by two nonparallel vectors $u$ and $v$ if we can express $w$ with $u$ and $v$. So there must be some scalars $a,b$ such that:

$$ w=au+bv$$

Now it is easy to see that $a=b=-1$ satisfies this equation.

Comment: yes....noted.  But that is not readily apparent to me from the diagram....what am I missing?  how this visible from this diagram?  Thanks.

Comment: Because you are looking at these vectors and the given plane. You have to multiplay $u$ and $v$ both with $-1$ and then add them. Try!

Comment: @jrive Rotate the diagram so you can see the three line segments from other angles. When you superimpose $u$ and $v$, you should see a single straight line segment.